# Como mostrar resultado dependente de dados de mais de um formulário com AJAX e PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo um catálogo de peças automotivas com formulário dependentes. Basicamente quem acessa o site seleciona o tipo de peça, a marca e o modelo (o formulário do modelo é dependente da marca). Depois quero mostrar as peças baseadas no tipo e modelo.

Meu código está assim:

```
<?php
  include('db.php');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- seleção do tipo -->
<select name="tipo" class="tipo">
  <option value="0">SELECIONE O TIPO</option>
<?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tipo");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['tipo_id'].'">'.$row['tipo_nome'].'</option>';
  } ?>
</select><br/><br/>

<!-- seleção da marca -->
<select name="marca" class="marca">
  <option>SELECIONE A MARCA</option>
    <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM marca");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['marca_id'].'">'.$row['marca_nome'].'</option>';
        } ?>
</select><br/><br/>

<!-- seleção do modelo -->
<select name="modelo" class="modelo">
  <option>SELECIONE O MODELO</option>
</select>

<!-- mostra as peças -->
<p name="pecas" class="pecas"> PEÇAS DISPONÍVEIS </p>

<!-- script para preencher o modelo -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $(".marca").change(function()
  {
  var marca_id=$(this).val();
  var post_id = 'id='+ marca_id;

$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: post_id,
  cache: false,
  success: function(modelo)
  {
   $(".modelo").html(modelo);
  } 
  });

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu ajax.php está assim:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['id']){
$id=$_POST['id'];
if($id==0){
    echo "<option>SELECIONE O MODELO</option>";
}else{
    echo "<option>SELECIONE O MODELO</option>";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `modelo` WHERE marca_id='$id'");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
         echo '<option value="'.$row['modelo_id'].'">'.$row['modelo_nome'].'</option>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Até aqui está tudo funcionando, agora eu preciso mostrar as peças com base na seleção do modelo E do tipo. A tabela das peças é assim:

Nome: produto
Campos: produto_id, modelo_id (vinculado ao modelo), tipo_id (vinculado ao tipo) e produto_nome

Tentei alterar o script com o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".marca").change(function()
{
var marca_id=$(this).val();
var post_id = 'id='+ marca_id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data: post_id,
cache: false,
success: function(modelo)
{
$(".modelo").html(modelo);
} 
});
});

$(".modelo").change(function()
{
var tipo_id=$(".tipo").val();
var modelo_id=$(".modelo").val();
var post_id = 'tipo_id='+ tipo_id + '&modelo_id=' + modelo_id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data: post_id,
cache: false,
success: function(peca)
{
$(".pecas").html(peca);
} 
});

});

});
</script>
```

E o ajax.php com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['id']){
$id=$_POST['id'];
if($id==0){
echo "<option>SELECIONE O MODELO</option>";
}else{
echo "<option>SELECIONE O MODELO</option>";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `modelo` WHERE marca_id='$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<option value="'.$row['modelo_id'].'">'.$row['modelo_nome'].'</option>';
    }
}
}
if($_POST['modelo_id'] && ['tipo_id']){
$modelo=$_POST['modelo_id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo_id']
if($id==0){
    echo "Não há peças disponíveis";
}else{
    echo "Peças disponíveis";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `produto` WHERE 
modelo_id='$modelo' and tipo_id='$tipo'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '"'.$row['produto_nome'].'"';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Porém, assim, ele para de funcionar completamente

Comment: Não é só fazer um select passando o modelo_id e tipo_id selecionados no seu where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessa linha

```php
if($_POST['modelo_id'] && ['tipo_id']){
// ....
```

Está faltando um `$_POST`, deveria ser assim

```php
if($_POST['modelo_id'] && $_POST['tipo_id']){
// ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div class="col-md-6">
                                  <select name="idTipologia" id="idTipologia" class="selectboxit" data-allow-clear="true" onchange="AlterarTipologia();">
                                     <?php
                                       $sqlTipologiaCusto = "SELECT * FROM `Table` ";
                                       $resultTipologiaCusto = $connection->query($sqlTipologiaCusto);
                                       while($rowTipologiaCusto = $resultTipologiaCusto->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $rowTipologiaCusto['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowTipologiaCusto['Nome']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <select name="idMetodo" id="idMetodo" class="dropdown"  >
                                   <option value="">Indique um IdTipologia</option>
                                 </select>
                               </div>
```

FUNCAO

```
 function AlterarTipologia()   {
      var idTipologia = $("#idTipologia").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Url/Lista.php",
        data: "idTipologia="+idTipologia,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          //alert(html);
          $("#idMetodo").html(html);
        }
      });
    }
```

codigo do ficheiro do URL

```
 $idTipologia = $_POST['idTipologia'];
 $sqlTipologiaCusto = "SELECT * FROM `PecasProcessosCompraMetodos` WHERE IdTipologia ='$idTipologia' ";
 $resultTipologiaCusto = $connection->query($sqlTipologiaCusto);

 echo '<option value="">Indique um Método</option>';
while($rowTipologiaCusto = $resultTipologiaCusto->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$rowTipologiaCusto['Id'].'">'.$rowTipologiaCusto['Nome'].'</option>';
```

}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).